# how to check the character count of a file in python

Tags: python, size, character

I have a python code which reads many files.
but some files are extremely large due to which i have errors coming in other codes.
i want a way in which i can check for the character count of the files so that i avoid reading those extremely large files.
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
os.stat(filepath).st_size
```

Assuming by ‘characters’ you mean bytes. ETA:

> i need total character count just like what the command 'wc filename' gives me unix

In which mode? `wc` on it own will give you a line, word and byte count (same as `stat`), not Unicode characters.

There *is* a switch `-m` which will use the locale's current encoding to convert bytes to Unicode and then count code-points: is that really what you want? It doesn't make any sense to decode into Unicode if all you are looking for is too-long files. If you really must:

```
import sys, codecs

def getUnicodeFileLength(filepath, charset= None):
    if charset is None:
        charset= sys.getfilesystemencoding()
    readerclass= codecs.getReader(charset)
    reader= readerclass(open(filepath, 'rb'), 'replace')
    nchar= 0
    while True:
        chars= reader.read(1024*32)  # arbitrary chunk size
        if chars=='':
            break
        nchar+= len(chars)
    reader.close()
    return nchar
```

`sys.getfilesystemencoding()` gets the locale encoding, reproducing what `wc -m` does. If you know the encoding yourself (eg. 'utf-8') then pass that in instead.

I don't think you want to do this.

Comment: hi bob ,
  i need total character count just like what the command 'wc filename' gives me unix

Comment: @randeepsp: Update your question with additional information.  Do not add this kind of important information in comments.

Comment: For counting bytes, `os.path.getsize(filepath)` is easier for me to remember than `os.stat(filepath).st_size` (thanks @Sapph)

Answer (score 7):

If you want the unicode **character** count for a text file given a specific encoding, you will have to read in the entire file to do that.

However, if you want the **byte** count for a given file, you want `os.path.getsize()`, which should only need to do a `stat` on the file as long as your OS has `stat()` or an equivalent call (all Unixes and Windows do).

Comment: Because of UTF coding schemes, it's possible that you'll have characters with a varying number of bytes.

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
import os
os.path.getsize(filePath)
```

to get the size of your file, in bytes.

Answer (score 4):

```
os.path.getsize(path)
```

> Return the size, in bytes, of path.
>   Raise os.error if the file does not
>   exist or is inaccessible.

Answer (score 2):

alternative way

```
f=open("file")
os.fstat( f.fileno() ).st_size
f.close()
```